# Wie sagt man "Well-stated questions" and "formal answers" auf Deutsch?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, idiom

Well I'm writing this short story about an Austrian mathemacian who came up with the mathematical notions of "well-stated questions" and "formal answers" and, to make it look more real, I would like to know how that could be translated in German.

I've little to no notion of German but I thought it may look like something like "gut stellt Fragen" but I am not sure at all. 
That's why I'm asking you know !

Thank you a lot for taking the time to help me !

Comment: At least it should be a participle, which would be "gestellte" and not "stellt".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I understanding correctly that these are not established mathematical concepts, but made up ones? If so, I'd suggest "wohlgestellte Fragen" (sg. "wohlgestellte Frage") and "formalisierte Antworten" (sg. "formalisierte Antwort").

If you're using them as object in a sentence (rather than subject) and want to correctly reflect that in the German case, here's the accusative sg and pl, respectively:

wohlgestellte Frage / wohlgestellten Fragen

formalisierte Antwort / formalisierten Antworten

Comment: Yes, totally made up !
I'm just unsing them to show what they would be in the fake original article but I'm using using them anywhere else.
Thanks a lot !